Completely metrizable space
Let $X$ be a completely metrizable space and $A$ a nonempty subset of $X$ that is simultaneously $F_\sigma$ and $G_\delta$ in $X$. Show that there is an open set $U$ such that $U\cap A$ is nonempty and closed in $U$.
I want to solve this problem using the Baire category theorem. A is $G_\delta$ so that it is completely metrizable.And it is of the second category. But I don’t know how to do next.

What is your motivation for this question? Is this an exercise? Or did you think about it?

Yes, this is true.
Let $X$ be a topological space, $A \subset B \subset X$.
With $int_B(A), cl_B(A)$ we denote the interior, respectively closure,
of $A$ with respect to the subspace topology of $B$,
$cl(A) = cl_X(A)$.
We need the following two lemmas, which should be well-known:
Lemma 1.
Let X be completely metrizable, $A$ a $G_\delta$-subset of $X$.
Then $A$ is completely metrizable.
Lemma 2.
Let $\emptyset \neq X$ be a Baire space,
$(F_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ be a sequence of closed subsets of $X$
with $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} F_n = X$.
Then there exists an $n \in \mathbb N$ such that
$int_X(F_n) \neq \emptyset$.
Now, let $\emptyset \neq A$ be a $G_\delta$ and $F_\sigma$ subset of the completely metrizable space $X$,
$A = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} F_n$, $F_n$ closed in $X$.
By lemma 1, $A$ is completely metrizable, hence it is Baire space.
By lemma 2, there exists $n \in \mathbb N$ such that
$int_A(F_n) \neq  \emptyset$.
Let $U$ be open in $X$ such that $int_A(F_n) = U \cap A$.
Then
$$cl_U(U \cap A) = cl(U \cap A) \cap U =
cl(int_A(F_n)) \cap U \subset cl(F_n) \cap U = F_n \cap U 
\subset U \cap A
$$
Hence, $U \cap A$ is closed in $U$.

Wow, thank you. This method looks so simple.
